# Chow's Lemma: Mumford's and Grothendieck's (?) definitions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-varieties

David Mumford gives in his book Algebraic Geometry I, Complex Projective Varieties
on page 61 a definition of Chow's Lemma which has at least for me not a
usual form:

If says that a closed $^*$-analytic subset $X \subset \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^n$
is a finite union of algebraic varieties.

On 'closed $^*$-analytic subset': on page 61 Mumford defined a locally closed
subset $X \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ as follows. Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ open set
and $X \subset U$ closed in $U$. Then $X$ is $^*$-analytic if $X$ can be decomposed
as

$$X = X^{(r)} \cup X^{(r-1)} \cup ... \cup X^{(0)} $$

where for all $i$, $ X^{(i)}$ is a $i$-dimensional complex submanifold of $U$ and
the closure $\overline{X^{(i)}} \subset 
X^{(i)} \subset X^{(i-1)} \subset ... \subset X^{(0)}$.

Now in modern literature the Chow's Lemma is known as (this one is from
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow%27s_lemma) but quoted from Grothendieck's EGA II):

> If $X$ is a scheme that is proper over a noetherian
> base $ S $, then there exists a projective $S$
> -scheme $ X' $ and a
> surjective $S$-morphism $  f:X'\to X $ that induces
> an isomorphism $  f^{{-1}}(U)\simeq U$  for some dense
> $U\subseteq X$.

Question: is there any relation between Mumford's version and Wikipedia
version. Remark: the wikipedia version is exactly that one from EGA II.

My conjecture: if $S= \operatorname{Spec} (\mathbb{C})$, ie $X$ is a
complex scheme or say for sake of simplicity a variety, are these two statements equivalent?
For example I don't know but probably the wikipedia version could be
proved by applying Mumford's version which allows using analytic methods.

But that's only a conjecture of mine, nothing more.
Does anybody know more on this issue?

Comment: Same Chow, different lemma.

Comment: Actually Mumford's book discusses the Chow *theorem*, which as Donu says has nothing to do with Chow's lemma.

Comment: Decades ago that version in Mumford _was_ known as Chow's Lemma, and the EGA II version had not yet achieved the same prominence, etc.

Comment: see section I.10 of Mumford's redbook for the classic version of the wikipedia Chow lemma.

Comment: Perhaps my earlier comment was a bit cryptic, but other people have clarified it. Let me add that Chow's name is attached to several different things in algebraic geometry. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wei-Liang_Chow